# Was ist »Bus mit den Leuten, die das interessiert«?

Tags: phrase

Wieso ist [dieser Artikel](http://www.der-postillon.com/2017/05/wayne.html) im „Der Postillon“ witzig? Es sieht so aus, als ob es im Voraus einen Witz schon gäbe, der mit „Der Bus mit den Leuten, die XY interessiert“ Glechgültigkeit ausdrückt und jemaden auslacht. Den Witz habe ich nie gehört und auch verstehe ich nicht, wieso soll der witzig sein. Normalerweise finde ich *den Postillon* lustig, aber dieses Mal verspasse ich bestimmt was Wichtiges.

Comment: At least in its current version the article contains a link to https://www.mundmische.de/bedeutung/28321-Wo_ist_eigentlich_der_Bus to explain the joke "Wo ist der Bus" for people like you and me who have never heard it before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um sein Desinteresse oder mangelnde Relevanz des Gesagten auszudrücken wurde früher nur "*das interessiert doch niemanden*" oder "*Wen interessiert das denn?*" benutzt.

Aus letzterem wurde in den letzten (20?) Jahren auch die Frage "*Wo ist der Bus mit den Leuten, die das interessiert?*". Vermutlich zunächst als Jugendsprache, das dann beibehalten wurde. Wer es benutzt, hält es offenbar für lustig.

**Der Postillion** greift dies auf und präsentiert eben diesen Bus, was m. M. N. durchaus lustig ist, im Gegensatz zur genannten Frage.

Answer (score 10):

Der Witz (so es denn wirklich einer ist), ist ein bißchen subtil:

Er geht zurück auf den Jugendsprache-Spruch: "Wo ist der Bus mit den Leuten, die das interessiert", was mehr oder weniger bedeutet, "du wirst ein paar an dem, was du grade sagst, interessierte Leute mit dem Bus ankarren müssen. Hier ist keiner.".

Zusätzlich heißen die Leute, die, als der Bus tatsächlich ankommt, drinsitzen, alle *Wayne* - Ein andrer Jugendspruch, kommt von "Wayne interessiert's" (ausgesprochen als "*wen*", also niemand).

Und um dem ganzen die Krone aufzusetzen, interessiert der Artikel, der das Ganze beschreibt, auch noch keinen - Er ist (absichtlich) weder interessant noch komisch, was sozusagen "rekursives Nicht-komisch/interessant-sein" bedeutet - Und das ist auf eine gewisse Art auch wieder komisch (weil man die Leute, die sich für den Artikel interessieren würden, eben auch wieder mit dem Bus ankarren müsste).

Comment: Oha! Ich dachte nicht, dass man aus diesem drögen Artikel etwas Interessantes herausholen könnte. Deine Antwort hat mich jedoch in der Tat erleuchtet. Vermutlich bin ich zu sehr aus Jugendsprachspielen draußen. Wer Nase.

Comment: Gelegentlich habe ich auch die Variante: "Wann kommt der Bus?" gehört.

Comment: Ich hab mich gekringelt vor Lachen, vor allem als am Ende noch alle Wayne hießen. So unterschiedlich kann Humor sein.

Comment: Naja, laut Artikel ist der Bus ja in der fiktiven Stadt Bielefeld angekommen, die wie man ja weiß, in Wahrheit gar nicht existiert: http://www.bielefeldverschwoerung.de Also ist der Bus mit den Leuten, die das interessiert, wohl doch noch immer unterwegs. Aber über die im Artikel leider nur angedeuteten Ausführungen zur [Abc-Vermutung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc-Vermutung) hätte ich gerne mehr erfahren.

Answer (score 2):

In vollendeter Form geht der "Witz" so:
Jemand erzählt etwas Uninteressantes. Statt zu sagen "Wo ist der Bus mit den Leuten, die es interessiert?" sagt man einfach nur "Wo ist denn der Bus hin?". Eventuell wiederholt man die Frage, bis der Erzähler genervt fragt: "Welcher Bus denn?". Und der Gelangweilte antwortet: "Der mit den Leuten, die es interessiert."
Man bringt also zunächst den Erzähler durch eine Zwischenfrage dazu seine Erzählung zu unterbrechen, um ihn dann mit der Pointe vollends zum Schweigen zu bringen.